# How to show jQuery content in PDF generated by using PDFKIT in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am using **PDFKIT** tool to generate **PDF** from **HTML** in **Rails**, it works fine, and generates pdf successfully. However there is a small problem, that it doesn't show the content which is generating by jQuery, for example, there is a range slider on the page, which is excluded in the PDF generated.

Here is the link of the URL I am trying to convert html to pdf:

http://ourdesignzdev.info:3001/employee/resume/download?id=22

and here is the output:

[image]

Please compare the **Skills** section, it doesn't show the slider.

Comment: "why is this happening" because resulting PDF doesn't run your jquery. It's a static document. If you want your circular ranges in the pdf, you can render them as images, for example.

Comment: i am sorry i didn't get you, if the stylesheet links are working properly then why not js?

Comment: Because styles is data and js is code (which changes the page).

Comment: oh, then what's the alternate, if we consider about images, then how many images should i create, because range varies from 0.1 to 100 :(

Comment: It seems that you can render your ranges as SVG and pdfkit should handle it just fine.

Comment: ok let me try, will get back to you, thanks

Comment: @SergioTulentsev hmmm yeah that's worked out, i have used SVG, it works fine, thanks so much :) :)